# Minimize multi-variable function with constraints one variable at a time

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

While minimizing two variable 
$$\min_{s\in\mathbb{R},x\in\mathbb{R^n}} \sqrt{x^TAx}-s $$ 
$$ subject\ to \ x^Te=1\ and \ x^Tu = s$$
A: n × n symmetric positive definite matrix

e: the n-vector of ones

μ: a given n-vector

Initially I fixed s and solved function with Lagrange multipliers to include constraints and get some value for x( $x^*(s)$). For the next step I replaced x with the value I found but I am not sure about including the $x^Tu=s$ constraint and solve it by Lagrangian method or should I just not include any constraint and directly use fermat theorem to find a minimum value for s.